# Browse Folders to open a file in python

Tags: python

I am working in a project in witch I want to browse directories then choose a file then open it. I am working with python, I tried the os module and tkfiledialog, but all i found is some commands to read the file with python. What I want is to open the file(like pdf or ppt) and play it on the screen. Can any one help me to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty OS dependent. On UNIX OSes (Linux, Mac OS) the `xdg-open` and `open` commands might do what you want.

Assuming the path to the file is in the `path_to_file` variable, you could use:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["open", path_to_file])      # Mac OS
subprocess.check_call(["xdg-open", path_to_file])  # Linux OSes
```

Comment: Thank you @Thomas , I tried this but it gave me this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ggggg.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(["open", '/home/helmi/Bureau/xx.jpg'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['open', '/home/helmi/Bureau/xx.jpg']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: @HelmiRomdhani Looks like you forgot to paste the error?

Comment: this is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ggggg.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(["open", '/home/helmi/Bureau/xx.jpg'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['open', '/home/helmi/Bureau/xx.jpg']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: What does `open /home/helmi/Bureau/xx.jpg` does when run **from your shell**?

Comment: Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

Comment: @HelmiRomdhani Oh, sorry. The command is `xdg-open` on Linux, not `open`.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, Super ! it works fine now as I want

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
os.system(r'c:\your_file.extension') #Example os.system(r'c:\test.pdf')
```

This will open whatever file you pass